# Springboot+Job Framework

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, jobs, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

My requirement is whenever we call certain RestAPI from UI/Postman, At backend it should trigger JOB that perform several operations/task.
Example:
Assume some POST Rest API is invoked -
It should invoke "Identify-JOB"(performs several activities)- Based on certain condition, It should invoke PLANA-JOB or PLANB-JOB
1> Suppose PLANA-JOB is invoked, on the success of this JOB, it should trigger another JOB called "finish-JOB". On the failure it should not invoke another JOB "finish-JOB"

Can you please help here how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use async processing and that'll trigger the first job and that task will trigger the next set of tasks.

You can build them like AWS step functions

You can use [Rqueue](https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue) to enqueue async task and that'll be processed by one of the listeners.

Comment: Other than this reddis queue mechanism, is there any other mechanism

Comment: You can use SQS, RabbitMQ, Kafka and other techniques as well.